# Replacing strings on a line in a file replaces empty lines

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I create a simple batch to replace a specific string in a file and dump the output to a new file:

```
set oldstring=SERVER_IP
set newstring=10.10.10.1

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (test.txt) do (
     set str=%%i
     set str=!str:%oldstring%=%newstring%!
     echo !str!>>newfile
 )
```

If I run it on a file containing caracter 'a' a line feed, then a white space and a line feed I get the wrong output.

```
a[lf]
 [lf]
```

OUPUT:

```
a
SERVER_IP=10.10.10.1
```

Why do I get this the string I'm trying to replace in the output whenever I have a line full of white spaces?

### EDIT

Expected output

```
a
```

Comment: What *should* your output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens, as `%%i` is empty for a line with white spaces.
`str` is also empty and empty variables are not defined.

To replace an empty variable fails, everything before the colon is dropped.

The line `set str=!str:%oldstring%=%newstring%!` will be evaluated to `set str=SERVER_IP=10.10.10.1!`.
The exclamation mark will be dropped due the delayed expansion, that's all.

You can check if `str` is defined.

```
....
if defined str (
    set str=!str:%oldstring%=%newstring%!
    echo(!str!>>newfile
)
```

Comment: I moved the output echo inside the IF so we don't get a "echo is off" message. But this worked very well.

Comment: Therefore I used `echo(!str!`. The parenthesis is important here, it avoids problems with empty strings and any other possible content in `!str!` like `ON`, `OFF`  or `/?`